# Python Text widget only opening in a window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have got this code to put a text widget in my code however when I run the entire code it only opens the text widget in a new window instead of adding it to the existing gui.
I'm quite new so do I need to add a command or something to specify it to go into the existing window?

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import random
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1600x8000")
root.title("Cafe au Lait")

tops = tk.Frame(root, width=1600, relief="sunken")
tops.pack(side="top")
f1 = tk.Frame(root, width=800, height=700, relief="sunken")
f1.pack(side="left")

roots = Tk()
t = Text(roots)
t.grid(row=6, column=6)
roots.grid_rowconfigure(6, weight=1)
roots.grid_columnconfigure(6, weight=1)

tk.Label(f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'),text="Takeaway",bd=16,anchor="w").grid(row=2, column=2)
txt_takeaway=tk.Entry(f1, font=('arial',16,'bold'),textvariable=takeaway,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",justify='right')
txt_takeaway.grid(row=2,column=3)

root.bind("<Return>", ref)

root.mainloop()
```

I have got that existing gui with the root = tk part added to it but its making a new window.

Comment: What you say is impossible. There is only one "gui" in the code you posted, and that is where the text widget is appearing. There must be more details that you have left out, such as what you mean by "the existing gui". In short, for it to go in an existing window, you need to make it a child of the existing window.

Comment: how do i make it a child of the existing window. Ill edit the original post to add the other gui

Comment: `roots = Tk()` explicitly creates a new window. Why are you doing that if you don't want another window? Have you worked through a tkinter tutorial so that you understand how widgets are created?

Comment: I did that because when i did it without it said 'cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack' i dont know what this means as all my other buttons and entry boxes use grid.

Comment: You're clearly using `pack`, I don't know why you think everything is using `grid`. The error message means exactly what it says: you can't mix `grid` and `pack` with widgets that share the same parent. You have to use one or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are explicitly creating a new window with this statement:

```
roots = Tk()
```

If you want to put the text widget in the first root window, remove that line and then make the text widget a child of the first root window:

```
t = Text(root)
```